# Changing the color a the title frame

Tags: beamer

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.00,0.00,0.50}

\setbeamercolor{title}{bg=myblue!80!white}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\mdseries}

 \usecolortheme[named=blue]{structure}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif} % rendre l'Ã©criture math plus beau (no necessary samcarter)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%\usepackage%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%-----
\usepackage{pifont} %bouni
%-----bclogo--------------
%\usepackage{soul} %suligne dans Bclogo
    %\setul{}{1.5pt}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
%\colorlet{bctitle}{Maroon}
%\renewcommand\bcStyleTitre[1]{\vskip-0.8em\bfseries\color{bctitle}\ul{#1}\vskip-0.7em}
%-----
%-----
\usepackage{fancybox} %pour faire l'encadrement
\newcommand{\cadre}[1]{
\setlength{\fboxsep}{7pt}
\begin{center}
\shadowbox{#1}
\end{center}}
%--------------------

%----------pabox----------
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{%
    colback=bg,
    colframe=blue!75!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    coltitle=blue!75!black,
    colbacktitle=bg,
    enhanced,
    attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-1.2mm, xshift=2mm},
  title=#2,
  #1}
%--------------------
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 %------------------------\AtBeginSubsection[]----------------------
    \AtBeginSubsection[]{   
        \begin{frame}<beamer>[noframenumbering,plain]{Outline}
            \transsplitverticalout
            \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
        \end{frame}
    }

\usetheme{Madrid}
%\usetheme[secheader]{Madrid}
%%%------begin Warsaw----------------------------------
%\usetheme{Warsaw}
%\setbeamertemplate{headline}{} % supprimer le headline
%------
    %-----------------------------footline-----------------------------
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}{
        \leavevmode%
        \hbox{%
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.22\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
                \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
            \end{beamercolorbox}%
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.71\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
                \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
    %            \hspace*{3em}
    %            \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{1ex}
            \end{beamercolorbox}%
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.07\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{page number in head/foot}%
    %            \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle\hspace*{3em}
                \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber
            \end{beamercolorbox}%
        }%
        \vskip0pt%
    }

\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{bg=gray,fg=black}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Title and author%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title[Title of the talk]{Title of the talk}
\author[Author(University of ..)]{Author}

%%------------------%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering,plain]

 \maketitle{}

\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{one}
\subsection{one}
\begin{frame}{The operator norm}

\end{frame}
\subsection{two}
\subsection{tree}
\section{two}

\section{three}

\end{document}
```

> I want to use the color `myblue` in the head and bottom. Also I hope that the number of the slide will be like `Author(University of ..)`.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following shortened MWE, I have used `\setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{bg=black,fg=white}`  to get a white page number on a black background (please compare with `\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{bg=black}`, the settings for the author). In order to color the background of the title in the color `myblue`, I have changed `\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}` from `{bg=blue}`  to `{bg=myblue}` and added `\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=myblue}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.00,0.00,0.50}

\setbeamercolor{title}{bg=myblue!80!white}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\mdseries}


\usecolortheme[named=blue]{structure}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\usetheme{Madrid}

    \setbeamertemplate{footline}{
        \leavevmode%
        \hbox{%
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.22\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
                \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
            \end{beamercolorbox}%
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.71\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
                \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
    %            \hspace*{3em}
    %            \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{1ex}
            \end{beamercolorbox}%
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.07\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{page number in head/foot}%
    %            \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle\hspace*{3em}
                \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber
            \end{beamercolorbox}%
        }%
        \vskip0pt%
    }


\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=myblue}
\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{bg=myblue}
\setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{bg=black,fg=white}


\title[Title of the talk]{Title of the talk}
\author[Author(University of ..)]{Author}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{The operator norm}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```